# Simulate LMM data with specific error values using R

Tags: r, self-study, mixed-model, dataset, simulation

I have a need to simulate data in R using the following:

Simulate data for 5 (or more) subjects, indexed by $i$, $(i=1,~...,~5)$ with $6$ observations per subject indexed by $t$ $(t=1,~2,~...,~6)$. Observations of the $Y$ variable are taken at various times $(\text{TIME}=2,~3,~5,~9,~11,~13)$, per subject using various assumptions about $u_{0i}$ , $u_{1i}$:
$$
Y_{ti} = (β_0 + u_{0i} ) + (β_1+ u_{1i})*\text{TIME}_t + ε_{ti}  \\
\text{where }ε_{ti} \sim\mathcal N(0, σ^2),~σ^2=0.01,~β_0=5,~β_1=0.7
$$
This is a problem I have been given (it is for a non credit course that I am taking for fun). Don't want the "answer", but maybe an example that I can build on or a suggestion or two.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @TedKaniuka. I took the liberty of editing your question w/ $\LaTeX$ to make it easier to read. Please make sure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: To generate these data, I think we'll need more information. It appears you have random effects on both the intercept, $\beta_0$, & the slope, $\beta_1$. You need to specify the distribution (almost always assumed to be normal), both variances, and the covariance b/t them.

Comment: Hi Ted - perhaps you could ask a couple of more specific direct questions of the form "How would I ...?" that would help fill in what you don't yet know how to do. We don't know what you can and can't do.